# Odoo 8 Python How To assign Many2many Or one2many XMLRPC Create object

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, xml-rpc

I need help with XMLRPC , I'm using python , i'm trying to create product variant and i need to assign value to field many2many , here's my code

```
   idProductLineAttributeLine = 
   models.execute_kw(db,uid,password,'product.attribute.line','create',
   [{'product_tmpl_id':idProduct,'attribute_id':idAttr,'value_ids': (6,0,
   [idValue])}])
```

if i'm assign normal field everythings work fine but when it comes to many2many field or one2many field its show arrow like this

```
in __dump\nTypeError: cannot marshal <type 'builtin_function_or_method'> objects\n", "message": "cannot marshal <type 'builtin_function_or_method'> objects", "name": "exceptions.TypeError", "arguments": ["cannot marshal <type 'builtin_function_or_method'> objects"]}}}
```

what did i do wrong? please help me :) , thank's in advanced

In the book odoo essential its said i must use this one too assign many2many value or one2many value but still no luck

```
(0,_ ,{' field': value}): This creates a new record and links it to this one
(1, id,{' field': value}): This updates values on an already linked record
(2, id,_): This unlinks and deletes a related record
(3, id,_): This unlinks but does not delete a related record
(4, id,_): This links an already existing record
(5,_,_): This unlinks but does not delete all linked records
(6,_,[ ids]): This replaces the list of linked records with the provided list
```

**updated**
 I manage to solve this problem by adding []  thx to dccdany for pointing this out :), and the product variant added to product

```
 models.execute_kw(db,uid,password,'product.attribute.line','create',   [{'product_tmpl_id':idProduct,'attribute_id':idAttr,'value_ids': (6,0,       [idValue])}])
```

, but the the product variant does not auto generate , i still need to manually refresh the product by editing and saved any idea why?

[image: http://imgur.com/WGLUbQo]

as seen in the screenshot there's 4 product variant but the status near top right only said 3 variant did i miss something here??

Comment: Did you try with [(6, 0, [ids])]?

Comment: aah i see i did it ,and how to update the current many2many relation?? i mean what if i want to add more value to many2many relation without replacing the value because if i try using [(6,0,[ids])]? it's keep replaceing the previous value can u give some example??how to use (0,0,{})

Comment: You can just pass the ID and 4: [(4, ID)]

Comment: no luck still not updated my product variant, I'm using this code to update the list
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.attribute.line', 'write',[[7],{'value_ids':(4,idValue)}])

Comment: Remember to put [ ],. [(4, ID)]

Comment: aaaah i see, can u explain more about it? =-=" because i keep missing [] idont really understand the difference :),,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142551/discussion-between-dmh-and-dccdany).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above code you are just adding new product.attribute.line.Technically odoo will create new attribute line but when product template write method will call at that time system will call method create_variant_ids and create new variants.

Following is the simplest way to create or update variants.

```
 models.execute_kw(db,uid,password,'product.attribute.line','create',   [{'product_tmpl_id':idProduct,'attribute_id':idAttr,'value_ids': (6,0,       [idValue])}])

 models.execute_kw(db,uid,password,'product.template','write',{'active':True})
```

When you call product template write method system will call method of create_variant_ids.

This may help you.

Comment: models.execute_kw(db,uid,password,'product.template','write',[[idProduct],{'active':True}]) :D thx .maybe this is what u mean :) , its really helped me